# Create bounding box from coordinates

Tags: maps, bounding-box

I need to create a bounding box b/w two coordinates.

For example I have a source and a destination coordinate, then I want to create a box that will include these two points.

I have uploaded an image in which you can refer what I am doing.

A,B points are the known coordinates, so I determined D,C using very basic geometry.

I am aware of the fact that the lines are not straight, but this was the easiest logic I can think of. Will this provide approximate results ?

If this is wrong please suggest some way.
[image]

Comment: If you're trying to define an axis-aligned rectangle, then yes, that's fine. If that's not what you're attempting to do, then please explain in more detail.

Comment: HI user1118321, didn't understood what you mean by "axis-aligned rectangle", I just need traffic info for a route, for that I require bounding box, so A,B are my source and destination and I created a box adding C,D

Comment: "Axis-aligned" just means that the sides of the rectangle will be parallel to the x and y axes of your drawing coordinate system. What you have seems perfectly fine. Are there any other requirements for this bounding box?

Comment: Nops, I don't think there are any further requirements, and also for my logic, it looks that a slightly approximate result shall work......